# To check Euclidean distance from center to map region in two regions

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel, grayscale, euclidean-distance

I have an 450x450 gray image. The neighbourhood of each pixel to be processed is defined by the Euclidean distance based on two radii, R1 and R2.  Hence:

- All pixels in the neighbourhood of R1 and R2 should be summed respectively.
- Each pixel mapped to R1 and R2 should be counted each pass.
- New Image should be ratio of these two regions: sum of pixels mapped to R1*Counter2 / sum of pixels mapped to R2*Counter1.

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

A neighborhood within Euclidean distance `R1` can be obtained as follows:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-R1:R1,-R1:R1);
r = x.^2 + y.^2;
k1 = r < R1.^2;
```

A convolution with this kernel leads to, for each output pixel, the sum of the pixels in its neighborhood:

```
sum1 = conv2(img, k1);
```

(where `img` is your image -- do make sure it is of a floating-point type, if it is of an integer type it is possible that the result of the sum cannot be represented correctly).

You can repeat the same code above for `R2`, leading to `sum2`, and then compute your ratio:

```
result = sum1 ./ sum2;
```